# useState to change quantity in multiple dropdowns

Tags: reactjs

I have several items listed on a page that can be added to a shopping cart. A Product component is being rendered for each product, and there is a form select as part of each component.

```
                  const [qty, setQty] = useState(1); 
                  ...
                        <Form.Control
                      className="w-100"
                      as="select"
                      value={qty}
                      onChange={(e) => {
                        setQty(e.target.value);
                      }}
                    >
```

If I useState this way, every product on the page has its Select Value changed when a change is made to the select because it is derived from the `qty` variable. Since I don't know how many products will be rendered on each page, how can I write a function that will only update the value of the product within the component being changed?

Comment: How do you render each of the product components? Can you share the component where you're rendering them?

Comment: I am using the map method to render each component. How can I declare `const [qty, setQty] = useState(1);` inside of the component so that each component has its own `useState` ?

Answer (score 0):

I learned you can `setState` and initialize it with an object. Once I update the state of a component rendered using the map method, I set the key of the state object with the id of the product. I was able to solve my problem with the code below.

```
                  const [qty, setQty] = useState({ int: 1 })...

                  <Form.Control
                  className="w-100"
                  as="select"
                  value={item._id in qty ? qty[item.id] : qty.int}
                  onChange={(e) => {
                    setQty({ ...qty, [item._id]: e.target.value });
                  }}
                >
```

Answer (score -2):

Hint: The `useState` should be inside the product component, every product component must have its own `useState` programmatically if you're using the `map` method.

---

Wow!!! -2?

---

## Update:

### Below is a demo:

[image]

#### Here's what I meant in code

Your `Product` component should look something like this:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

const productFromServer = [
  { id: 1, name: "Bread", qty: 0 },
  { id: 2, name: "Sugar", qty: 0 },
  { id: 3, name: "Butter", qty: 0 },
  { id: 4, name: "Tea", qty: 0 },
];

export const Product = () => {
  const [products, setProducts] = useState(productFromServer); // or useEffect

  const handleQuantityChange = (id, qty) => {
    const updatedProducts = products.map((product) => {
      if (product.id === id) {
        product.qty = qty; // update the quantity of the product
        return product;
      }
      return product;
    });
    setProducts(updatedProducts); // update the product state
  };

  console.log(products);

  return (
    <>
      <h1>Product Page</h1>
      <div className='product-container'>
        {products?.map(({ id, name, qty }) => {
          return (
            <div key={id} className='product-card'>
              <h2>{name}</h2>
              <p>Quantity: {qty}</p>
              <QtySelect
                id={id}
                qty={qty}
                handleQuantityChange={handleQuantityChange}
              />
            </div>
          );
        })}
      </div>
    </>
  );
};
```

While your `QtySelect` component should look as follow:

> I use the native select tag for the demo, but should still work as intended with other UI libraries

```
const QtySelect = ({ id, qty, handleQuantityChange }) => {
  return (
    <select
      className='w-100'
      value={qty}
      onChange={(e) => {
        handleQuantityChange(id, Number(e.target.value));
      }}
    >
      <option value={1}>1</option>
      <option value={2}>2</option>
    </select>
  );
};
```